# In RxJS what is the best way to subscribe a one time listener for the next event that met a certain condition?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Could some RxJS expert tell me if my way of subscribing to a one time listener for the next event that met a certain condition is alright or if there is an obviously better way?
I would like a pattern that I could apply with any type of event and I want the type of my event to be inferred in the end.

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { first, map } from "rxjs/operators"

//I have this subject...
const subject = new Subject<{
    eventName: "TEXT";
    text: string;
} | {
    eventName: "AGE";
    age: number;
}>();

//... An I want to subscribe this callback for the next text event..
const next= (text: string) => console.log(text);

//...Is this the best type-safe way to do it? 
subject
  .pipe(map(data => data.eventName === "TEXT" ? [data.text] : null))
  .pipe(first((data): data is NonNullable<typeof data> => !!data))
  .subscribe(([text])=>next(text))
  ;

subject.next({
  "eventName": "TEXT",
  "text": "Hello World"
});
```

[**run the code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-question?embed=1&file=index.ts)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `filter` operator before the `first` operator.
Plus, if you want some type checks, you can also add some type definitions for the events which are going to be emitted by the Subject.

Consider also that using `first` you will complete the subscription to the stream after the first event of type TEXT is emitted, so any subsequent event emitted will be ignored by that subscription.

This is the code you can use

```
type TextEvent = {
    eventName: "TEXT";
    text: string;
};
type AgeEvent = {
    eventName: "AGE";
    age: number;
};

//I have this subject...
const subject = new Subject<TextEvent | AgeEvent>();

//... An I want to subscribe this callback for the next text event..
const next= (text: string) => console.log(text);

//...Is this the best type safe way to do it ? 
subject
  .pipe(
    filter(event => event.eventName === 'TEXT'),
    first()
  )
  .subscribe( {
    next: (event: TextEvent ) => console.log(event.text),
    complete: () => console.log('DONE')
  }
  );

// this is not going to be printed
subject.next({
  eventName: "AGE",
  age: 99
});
// this IS going to be printed
subject.next({
  eventName: "TEXT",
  text: "Hello World - I will be printed since I am the first TEXT event to be emitted"
});
// this IS NOT going to be printed
subject.next({
  eventName: "TEXT",
  text: "I WILL NOT BE PRINTED since I come after the first TEXT event emitted"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply but this solution is not good for me. 
It requires to define type aliases for TextEvent and AgeEvent.
Also in the next function, adding TextEvent annotation is not safe, it is the equivalent of asking the compiler to trust me. But I don't want to be trusted I am not worthy of the compiler trust.
From a performance point of view though, your solution is better I'll give you that.